# Comma before a verb

Tags: commas

> Altimeter Group provides research and advisory for companies ***,*** enabling them to pursue new opportunities and business models.

Is the comma before *enabling* necessary and right in that sentence?

Comment: It's not necessary, though it's not incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Contrast

> Most heads of department are happy to provide support for teachers doing all they
>   can to ensure the children receive a sound education.

with

> Most heads of department are happy to provide support for teachers, doing all they
>   can to ensure the children receive a sound education.

The comma ensures that the -ing clause isn't wrongly taken to be modifying the preceding noun (assuming, of course, that is what is intended).